# Get UserID not working occassionally with Facebook GraphAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, userid

I am having some issues with an app I made recently. 
It's a voting app that is supposed to allow voting once per day for every user. 
So I am taking the userId and placing every userId in a database, however occasionally I get userId = 0 and I have no idea why is that. I am getting browser info as well wanted to check that it might be browser-related but it happened on both Mozilla and IE.

Here is the code below if that helps.

index.php (code I use for nonfans)

```
<?php header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');?>
<?php 
require 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout URL will be needed depending on the current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,
                                       'fbconnect' => 0,
                                       'next' => 'xxx',
                                       'cancel_url' => 'xxx' ));
  echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
}

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
function parsePageSignedRequest() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      return $data;
    }
    return false;
  }
  if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
    if($signed_request->page->liked) {
      echo("<script> location.href='revealed.php'</script>");
    } else {
      echo "<img src=\"non-fans.jpg\" width=\"520\" height=\"483\">";
    }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center; margin:0; overflow:hidden;">
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'xxx', status: true, cookie: false, xfbml: true});
    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
  }, 250);
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the reveal tab - the main app.

```
<?php 
require 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "xxx";
$app_secret = "xxx";
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

function getBrowser()
{
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
        $ub = "Firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Google Chrome';
        $ub = "Chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Apple Safari';
        $ub = "Safari";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Opera';
        $ub = "Opera";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Netscape';
        $ub = "Netscape";
    }

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
}

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();
$yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#voting-form").validate();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'xxx', status: true, cookie: false, xfbml: true});
    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
  }, 250);
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Let me know if you need the queries info but I doubt that's the problem as it works in 99 out of 100 votes.

Answer (score 2):

for some extrange reason sometimes the server doesn't recognize that the user is already logged in (at least that's what I think since I'm having the same issue), so you have to attempt to log the user again to get a proper access token.
This is how I do it:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();   
if(!$user) 
{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'publish_stream,email'));
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
```

And that it's supposed to work, but I can't really guarantee you anything. Hope this helps.